# How to show/hide divs

Tags: html, show-hide

I am trying to figure out how to do this...  I have 4 divs that I am looking to show and hide one at a time.  The link to the divs are in a separate nested div.  Here's my code:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="roundbox">
        <ul>
            <li class="t">
                <a href="">Main</a>
            </li>
            <li class="e">
                <a href="">News</a>
            </li>
            <li class="t">
                <a href="">History</a>
            </li>
            <li class="e">
                <a href="">Contact</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="inceptioncontent">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="contentnest">
                <div id="1"></div>
                <div id="2"></div>
                <div id="3"></div>
                <div id="4"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the Main, News, Contact, and History links to show/hide the corresponding divs in the contentnest div.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JQuery is great at doing his sort of thing. This looks like a good place to start: http://papermashup.com/simple-jquery-showhide-div/

Comment: Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7W4KL/1/) doing it according to your example.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7W4KL/11/

I came up with the above partial solution based on your JSFiddle, Shahar.  What I want to know how to do now is make it so only one div is visible at a time.  Any help?

Comment: Selected as the answer because it led me in the right direction.  Used jQuery to accomplish task.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your looking for a drop down menu. You can achieve this:
Coding it in Javascript + css ( with a framework like jQuery it will be easier)
; With Css
; Downloading A plugin

I think the "Css only" is the best way, jQuery is cool and download a plugin it's the easiest way, but you need the js of the user's explorer to be on.

You can check how to do it only with css here:

https://www.grc.com/menudemo.htm